# How to test sqlite capacitor with ionic react in browser before move it on Android and IOS

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, android-sqlite, capacitor

I am new at writing app with Ionic using React with js!
I am trying to implement the storage of coordinates (lon/lat) from the app using the capacitor-community/sqlite plugins inside sqlite on the mobile. 
Since the browser is not supported and in fact I get this message

```
Error: Not implemented on web.
at CapacitorSQLiteWeb.unimplemented (web-plugin.js:65)
```

I cannot test my code before to move the app on Android and IOS. 
At the moment I am using

- ionic 6.13.1
- react 16.12
- capacitor 3.0.0-rc.4
- capacitor-community/sqlite 3.0.0-beta.13

At the moment I am testing the app code in the browser
So having said my question is

how you suggest I can write/test code for the app using the sqlite capacitor plugin? 

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: i dont think you can

Comment: @AaronSaunders thanks for your comment :) 
so how real devs do that ?

I am not a real expert in js nor in react so, write code, create an apk and see if this works on a virtual device, really doesn't speed up the process :(

Comment: Late to the post but most devs test using the virtual devices in Android Studio or the mac dev environment.